# Android app emulating touch input

Tags: android, input, camera, touch, touchscreen

I am looking into developing a new input method on the Android platform that would emulate the touch input of the screen, is it possible to create a service that can interact directly or indirectly with the touch API to achieve this?

Specifics:
The interactions will come in the form of colour tracking from the camera which is processed into x/y coordinates and touch:0/1 events. Is it possible to have these interact with the touchscreen just as if it were a touch on the screen itself?

I understand that there may be permission problems with this approach of 'injection' control or piggybacking?

Also this is a technical exercise for an experimental report rather than a distributable app/piece of software so root/modifications are not a problem.

I have searched to no avail on the subject (at least not on the android platform) and i would like to find out the feasibility/difficulty of the project before undertaking it so any input would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of guessing here, but MotionEvent has some set...-functions like setLocation(float x, float y). There is also MotionEvent.Pointer to play with.